# getting error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')" on useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I'm trying to use useState in my react app, but as soon as I add in the line of code to initialize useState it throws a popup error with the error message: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

```
function AppComponent() {
    const [token,setToken] = React.useState('');
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(window.__token__)
        if(window.__token__) {
            setToken(window.__token__);
        }
    },[]);

    const {Provider} = tokenContext;
    return(
        <Provider value={token}>
            <Layout>
                <Header />
                <Content>
                    <CardsList />
                </Content>
            </Layout>
        </Provider>
    );
}
export const App = hot(AppComponent);
```

error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at Object.useState (E:\web\react\2less\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1620:21)
    at AppComponent (webpack://2less/./src/App.tsx?:16:47)
    at eval (webpack://2less/./src/server/server.js?:14:95)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\web\react\2less\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\web\react\2less\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\web\react\2less\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\web\react\2less\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\web\react\2less\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (E:\web\react\2less\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (E:\web\react\2less\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
```

Comment: You only setToken on initial render and you don't check later if it has changed. Add `window.__token__` to your dependency array in useEffect

Comment: I added, unfortunately it did not help either